# Adobe illusrator 2d, creating simple dent like effect on skin

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to create a logo where an item is tightly secured to human skin, like it was tied up with rope and I want to make it look like there's something behind that objects that would indicate that it dents the skin. You know like as if you pushed pencil on your skin it would create a small dent since the skin is flexible and some small wrinkles would appear around it. It musn't be very detailed but I want it to look like the items is slightly buried in the skin due to pressure from the "rope". Drop shadow looks good on other items but it doesn't give this flexible-skin like effect when it comes to this.

Any ideas how to create such effect that would indicate this item is placed against the skin and it makes it stretch a little?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question might not be terribly well suited for a q and a format. But start by telling what you have tried so far.

Comment: When you say "human skin", do you mean a photograph of human skin? If so, I'd use Photoshop, not Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

One, simple, method would be to use a gradient fill...

[image]

For a touch more, you could curve the outer edges of objects towards the indentation...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An old case, but still interesting.

You ask actually a way to create an illusion of 3D, but as drawn in a 2D program. The trick has been used in manual painting hundreds of years, it was developed as perfect as possible already in the Italian renaissance and Dutch art.

Illustrators 3D revolve effect could in theory create an image of perfectly round smoothly curved dent with very low effort and shade it plausibly. Draw only the revolved profile and set the viewing direction, perspective an light. Here's an example in a legacy Illustrator version (the new one is totally different). There's a guessed dent profile and a blue round stick profile revolved at the same time:

[image]

Integrating it to a bigger drawing is tricky, but it is possible. The viewing direction and the light can be changed freely.

Unfortunately 3D revolve is useless if the half-sunken part is for ex. rectangular -  a round dent doesn't fit.

If the drawing style in Illustrator is simple enough manually drawn dent doesn't need much effort nor highly polished skills. See the next simple brick on a plane:

[image]

The brick is 3 distorted rectangles, so the perspective is not the finest possible, but it is not a problem in this case. I said it's on the green plane, but as well it could be in a rectangular hole which fits perfectly.

Let's make the hole bigger and rounded:

[image]

3 parts are inserted with different colors. The vertical straightness of the hole is ambiguous. You want obviously edges which join to the plane with a smooth rounding. There's obviously less light in the dent, so we use gradient coloring and blurred black low opacity curve to make the shading:

[image]

The inserted parts are also copied below the image. The blurred black curve has non-uniform width. It must be narrow in the middle and at the ends.

There's no wrinkles. In reality they appear if the surface is stretched non-uniformly. This simplistic style cannot produce them. In line drawings one could draw them as curves, but they do not fit this shaded style:

[image]

Coloring the line drawing is not especially difficult if one uses watercolor like strokes which respect loosely or not at all the lights and shadows of the bumps. I skip it.

To get perfectly shaded wrinkles without having painter's skills one
must use a 3D program. Monsters, like Blender have also materials and adjustable lights for photorealistic rendering. And more: They can even calculate realistic forms for the dent and its wrinkles, if one bothers to create a physics model for the skin and the body below it. I'm afraid absorbing the needed knowledge takes an year  as full-time studying.

In a simple (CAD-like) program one can loft a surface through the guessed profiles of the dent. Here's one guess:

[image]

To get a dent the rectangle should be in the bottom and the rest of the curves must be elevated to higher. Here's my lofting result:

[image]

The program unfortunately refuses to hide all black curves. The ones which are considered as working borders stay. In addition the shading is algorithmic, there's no adjustable lights nor materials. It's OK for CAD-like purposes, but an artist surely wants more.

The rectangle is in the next image extruded to a brick to see how the dent fits:

[image]

It looks plausible, but the black curves, lack of color and obscure light make the result virtually unusable as a part of an illustration.

I checked the result also after exporting it to another simple program which has a little better rendering and it allows colors.  But there's another caveat: The triangulated 3D mesh is well visible, there's no automatic smoothed rendering:

[image]

In addition, there's no method to export the rendered image as a vector drawing. It's a bitmap. Only a line drawing is available as vector.

**Conclusion:** To get well shaded wrinkles (not a line drawing) one must be able to paint them or use a pro quality 3D program, nothing simple gives plausible results.